# How to Scroll to a Specific ID item in ScrollView inside different activity? Android Studio

Tags: javascript, java, android

I want to create a button that redirects to the scrollview's specific item ID.
But my destination scroll view is in a different activity.

example : my button is in activity A.
I want this button to point to Activity B, at the exact item ID coordinates inside some scrollview.

```
 public void HafalanHarian(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HafalanHarian.class);
            ScrollView sv = findViewById(R.id.ScrollHafHar);// your scrollview
            View insideView = findViewById(R.id.BoxDefinisi);// find the View that you need to scroll to which is inside this ScrollView
            sv.scrollTo(0, (int)insideView.getY());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

I have tried using the script above, but failed

hope someone can give me proper script

Comment: Pass the coordinates to the Activity B and then scroll to the required view.

Comment: can you tell me the correct script?